# Subscript out of range error for subroutine

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do a copy of data between different workbooks. The name for the workbooks happened to be random since users are given the option to select the file names, so I did a set of workbook in my codes. When I included a subroutine into my program, it stated subscript out of range.

Any ideas on how to ensure that the subroutine continue to understand my definition of the workbooks?

My codes are simplified in case you don't quite understand the rationale behind the first sub:

```
Option Explicit
Sub testwe()
Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, vFile As Variant
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 

vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open vFile
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook 'set the opened file as wb2

Call test123
End Sub

 sub test123()
 wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
 End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you declare `wb` and `wb2` for test123. If I run you code without `Option Explicit` set I get an `Object Required` error. Also, are you sure `wb2` will have a worksheet named `Sheet1`?

Comment: @DougGlancy you are right, I tried the code again it showed run time error instead of the one I stated.. Kind of weird. I am sure wb2 has Sheet1.

Comment: Assuming the error happens in `test123` the `subscript out of range` error would mean there's no "Sheet1" - spelled exactly like that. I can't see another reason for it, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make **wb** and **wb2** Global:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

Sub testwe()
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls", _
        1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
    'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open vFile
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook 'set the opened file as wb2
    Call test123
End Sub

 Sub test123()
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
 End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**:

This version uses Doug's suggestion:

```
Sub testwe()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls", _
        1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
    'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open vFile
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook 'set the opened file as wb2
    Call test123(wb, wb2)
End Sub

 Sub test123(wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook)
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I learnt another thing about setting them globally

Comment: That's bad advice. You should avoid the use of global variables unless necessary. Instead, pass the workbooks as variables to your subroutine. Also, this doesn't answer the original `subscript out of range` question.

Comment: Hi Doug:  passing them as parameters is a great idea......I had not considered it.....subscript out of range might indicate a "Sheet1"  v.s.  "Sheet 1"  spelling problem.

Comment: @DougGlancy you are right, for the display code, I am able to run it without the out of range issue, but when it comes to my full lenght, the out of range issue showed up

Comment: @Gary'sStudent passing them as parameters, do u mean doing a        "Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook over at Sub test123()"?